# Time efficiency on std::tr1::unordered_map::operator[]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, hash, optimization

I am optimizing a piece of code in Visual Studio 2008 SP1. Knowing that `unorder_map` is awesome with constant time insert/delete/find, so I optimized the code by using `unordered_map` as my primary data structure. Please take a look at the following code.

```
....
    typedef std::tr1::unordered_map <__int64, int> umap_id;
    const int text1_length = text1.GetLength();
    const int text2_length = text2.GetLength();
    const int max_d = text1_length + text2_length - 1;
    const bool doubleEnd = (64 < max_d);
    vector<set<pair<int, int> > > v_map1;
    vector<set<pair<int, int> > > v_map2;
    vector<int> v1(2 *max_d, 0);
    vector<int> v2(2 *max_d, 0);

    int x, y;
    __int64 footstep;
    umap_id footsteps(max_d * 2);
    bool done = false;
    const bool forward = ((text1_length + text2_length) % 2 == 1);

    for (int d = 0; d < max_d; ++d)
    {
        // Walk forward path one step
        v_map1.push_back(set<pair<int, int> >());
        for (int k = -d; k <= d; k += 2)
        {
            if (k == -d || (k != d && v1[k - 1 + max_d] < v1[k + 1 + max_d]))
                x = v1[k + 1 + max_d];
            else
                x = v1[k - 1 + max_d] + 1;
            y = x - k;

            if (doubleEnd)
            {
                footstep = (__int64) ((__int64)x << 32 | y);
                if (!forward)
                    footsteps[footstep] = d;
                else if (footsteps.find(footstep) != footsteps.end())
                    done = true;
            }
            ....
        }
    }
....
```

But turns out it is still quite slow. Given my relatively small input (`max_d`=946), it runs for more than 20 seconds.

I did a profiler analysis on the **release** build, and the profiler reveals that line: `footsteps[footstep] = d;` is the major culprit which was run 447931 times and took about 20 seconds.

Note, there is another line of code in the same loop body: `else if (footsteps.find(footstep) != footsteps.end())` which executed the same number of times (i.e. 447931 times) but costed much fewer seconds.

The `operator::[]` of `unordered_map` seems a black-box for me. I couldn't figure out why it takes so long. It's a **32-bit** application. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which STL implementation are you using?

Comment: Visual C++ by Microsoft, thanks

Comment: too many `::` and `<`, `>`, and casts to be C. Tag removed

Comment: Which version of Visual C++ (including service packs applied)?  I know that there were fixes to the TR1 library in VC2008 SP1, so if you're running VC2008 without the service pack, you might want to see if the SP helps (or see if VC2010 fixes the problem).

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your reply. My VC++ is updated, Version 3.5 SP 1.

Comment: Are you compiling in debug or release mode?

Comment: @jalf, in release mode. I have updated the post.

Comment: @Zeiga - you've given the version of the .NET Framework associated with the Visual Studio Installation (and from that it looks like you're using VS 2008). A more useful version number would be the one on the left column immediately below "Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx".  For example, my VS2008 installation (without SP1) says "9.0.21022.8 RTM" and my VS 2010 installation says "10.0.30319.1 RTMRel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2008 without SP1 (but with the Feature Pack that gives you the TR1 library) the default hash function for `tr1::unordered_map<>` only considers the lower 32 bits of the key value. At least that's by my reading of the `template<class _Kty> class hash::operator()` implementation in the `<functional>` header.

The `footstep` variable that's the key uses whatever is calculated for `y` as its lower 32 bits - is there enough variation in y that it would make a good hash value all on its own (I can't tell what the code that's calculating `y` is doing)?  If not, you may be putting many more items into a particular hash bucket than you'd like, and generating too many collisions.

You might want to consider providing your own hash function if that's the case.

By the way, it looks like VS 2010 has specializations for the `hash::operator()` when used with 64-bit integers so it'll hash all 64 bits - if you're using VS 2010, the speculation in my answer should not apply.

---

Update:

After some testing, I'm convinced this is the problem (the problem also exists in VS 2008 SP1). You can fix this by upgrading the compiler to VS 2010 which has better hash functions for 64-bit types or use your own hash function to handle this yourself. The following is one I tested quickly in VS2008, and it seems to work:

```
class hash_int64
    : public unary_function<__int64, size_t>
{
public:
    typedef __int64 key_t;
    typedef unsigned int half_t;

    size_t operator()(const key_t& key) const
    {   
        // split the 64-bit key into 32-bit halfs, hash each
        // then combine them
        half_t x = (half_t) (key & 0xffffffffUL);
        half_t y = (half_t) (((unsigned __int64) key) >> 32);

        return (hash<half_t>()(x) ^ hash<half_t>()(y));
    }
};
```

Then change your `typedef` to:

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map <__int64, int, hash_int64> umap_id;
```

Comment: awesome! It reduces my running time down to 4 seconds. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeiga: what does your profiler say now? 4 seconds still sounds like a lot (but maybe it's in another part of the code where it makes sense).

Answer (score 2):

In debug build the STL coming with Visual Studio makes heavy use of iterator checking and small nested functions, which get all inlined in release build. That's why debug code utilizing the STL is extremely slow compared to release code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But actually, my profiler results are based on Release build, not Debug build. Debug build will take much longer.

Comment: Even in release builds, the default is `#define _SECURE_SCL=1`.

Comment: Starting with VS 2010, `_SECURE_SCL=0` in release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting a lot of collisions. If unordered_map is implemented with a hash function to create the index and you get a lot of collisions it'll have to traverse a list to get to your item. This might be one reason, but i never looked at the unordered_map implementation.

Comment: It is possible. Unfortunately, my Profiler is not advanced enough to see what is going on internally.

Answer (score 0):

Hash maps are known to have quite high constant overhead. Only 946 elements, with a basically free comparison operator, should probably use the O(log(n)) lookup of `std::map`. However, there's no reason that `operator[]` should cost more time than `find()`, unless there's an implementation bug.

Comment: Note that there are nested loops - there are 447931 items being added to the `unordered_map`, not 946.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2005 and 2008, you should manually set `_SECURE_SCL=0`. It defaults to enabled, even in release builds, which adds a lot of runtime checks, which can be very costly in some cases.

Visual Studio 2010 fixes this, defaulting to actually making release builds *fast*.

Apart from this, it may be worth experimenting with replacing the data structure with a plain old `std::map`. And of course, as long as you use 64-bit integer keys in a 32-bit build is non-optimal too.

Targeting x64 may improve things noticeably, but if you're stuck on 32-bit, you could consider whether it is possible to replace the integer keys with doubles, since the CPU can handle those natively (I don't know what the default hashing function for doubles look like though, and it is possible it will be slower overall, but it may be worth testing at least)